# Reindexing sums in Isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I'm trying to translate the argument I gave in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3192900/prove-f-mu-f/3193391#3193391) into Isabelle and I [managed](https://github.com/rjraya/Isabelle/blob/master/ANT/Fourier.thy) to prove it almost completely. However, I still need to prove:

```
"(∑k | k ∈ {1..n} ∧ d dvd k. f (k/n)) =
        (∑q | q ∈ {1..n/d}. f (q/(n/d)))" for d :: nat
```

My idea was to use this theorem:

```
sum.reindex_bij_witness
```

however, I cannot instantiate the transformations i,j that relate the sets S,T of the theorem. In principle, the setting should be:

```
S = {k. k ∈ {1..n} ∧ d dvd k}
T = {q. q ∈ {1..n/d}}
i k = k/d
j q = q d
```

I believe there is a typing error. Perhaps I should be using div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, note that instead of `gcd a b = 1`, you should write `coprime a b`. That is equivalent (at least for all types that *have* a GCD), but it is more convenient to use.

Second, I would not write assumptions like `⋀n. F n = …`. It makes more sense to write that as a `defines`, i.e.

```
lemma
  fixes F :: "nat ⇒ complex"
  defines "F ≡ (λn. …)"
```

Third, `{q. q ∈ {1..n/d}}` is exactly the same as `{1..n/d}`, so I suggest you write it that way.

To answer your actual question: If what you have written in your question is how you wrote it in Isabelle and `n` and `d` are of type `nat`, you should be aware that `{q. q ∈ {1..n/d}}` actually means `{1..real n / real d}`. If `n / d > 1`, this is actually an *infinite* set of real numbers and probably not what you want.

What you actually want is probably the set `{1..n div d}` where `div` denotes division on natural numbers. This is then a *finite* set of *natural* numbers.

Then you can prove the following fairly easily:

```
lemma
  fixes f :: "real ⇒ complex" and n d :: nat
  assumes "d > 0" "d dvd n"
  shows "(∑k | k ∈ {1..n} ∧ d dvd k. f (k/n)) =
           (∑q∈{1..n div d}. f (q/(n/d)))"
  by (rule sum.reindex_bij_witness[of _ "λk. k * d" "λk. k div d"])
     (use assms in ‹force simp: div_le_mono›)+
```

### A note on div

`div` and `/` denote the same function, namely `Rings.divide.divide`. However, `/` for historic reasons (and perhaps in fond memory of Pascal), `/` additionally imposes the type class restriction `inverse`, i.e. it only works on types that have an `inverse` function.

In most practical cases, this means that `div` is a general kind of division operation on rings, whereas `/` only works in fields (or division rings, or things that are ‘almost’ fields like formal power series).

If you write `a / b` for natural numbers `a` and `b`, this is therefore a type error. The coercion system of Isabelle then infers that you probably meant to write `real a / real b` and that's what you get.

It's a good idea to look at the output in such cases to ensure that the inferred coercions match what you intended.

### Debugging non-matching rules

If you apply some rule (e.g. with `apply (rule …)`) and it fails and you don't understand why, there is a little trick to find out. If you add a `using [[unify_trace_failure]]` before the `apply`, you get an error message that indicates where exactly the unification failed. In this case, the message is

```
The following types do not unify:
(nat ⇒ complex) ⇒ nat set ⇒ complex
(real ⇒ complex) ⇒ real set ⇒ complex
```

This indicates that there is a summation over a set of reals somewhere that should be a summation over a set of naturals.